# Can someone explain what exactly each score of the BLOSUM62 matrix means?

Tags: bioinformatics, mutations

The descriptions that I've found say it's the log odds ratio (observed/expected) where expected is the assumption that there is no correlation between amino acids.

I'm slightly confused as to what this means? Do we have a database of sequences and if there are 10 A's out of 1000 amino acids is it's expected simply 10/1000 * sequence length for all sequences?

What is the observed? Is the observed different for every sequence so there is a different BLOSUM matrix for each sequence? And can someone explain how this table represents 62% of "kept identity"?

Sorry if these questions seem nonsensical or vague, I'm not of a biology background.

Comment: From your bio you appear to have an interest in computing science and mathematics. I am not sure that the answer to this question is mathematically complex (although it is outside my sphere) but it appears quite extensive and may not be suitable for anyone who understands it to present here. For that reason I give you a link to an account I found on line. If someone wants to present an introduction in an answer fine. Likewise if you are still not clear how the blocks are selected (that's the easy part) say. http://www.cs.columbia.edu/4761/assignments/assignment1/reference1.pdf

Comment: @David Thanks! This is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. Quick question on expected freq though. Is each sequence given its own BLOSUM scoring matrix and the expected freq is generated for different profiles of proteins?

Comment: I have voted to mark this as a duplicate and have modied the overlapping question and my own answer to it to take into account the specific concerns of the Poster her. I think that this is the best way of deal with this. Anyone who wishes to add or extend an answer to the previous question is, of course, free to do so.